# Склеить данные из двух массивов

Tags: php

Есть два массива:

```
$fdomain = $_POST['domains'];
$fdomain = explode(PHP_EOL, $fdomain);

$fip = $_POST['ip'];
$fip = explode(PHP_EOL, $fip);
```

Как из них получить массив вида:

```
fdomain - fip
```

Буду благодарен за помощь.

данные массивов для примера:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=> string(8) "test.ru "
  [1]=> string(9) "site2.ru "
  [2]=> string(7) "test.in"
} 

array(3) {
  [0]=> string(14) "111.11111.111 "
  [1]=> string(12) "2222.22.222 "
  [2]=> string(11) "333.333.333"
}
```

То есть на выходе нужен такой массив:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=> string(*) "test.ru - 111.11111.111"
  [1]=> string(*) "site2.ru - 2222.22.222"
  [2]=> string(*) "test.in - 333.333.333"
}
```

Comment: @AntonShchyrov массив, со значениями: `test.ru - 111.11111.111` и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался:

```
$new_arr = array();
$cnt = count($fdomain);

for($i = 0; $i<$cnt; $i++) {
    $new_arr[] = $fdomain[$i].' - '.$fip[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$merge = function ($domain, $ip) {
  return $domain . ' - ' . $ip;
};

$data = array_map($merge, $fdomain, $fip);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$fdomain = $_POST['domains'];
$fdomain = explode(PHP_EOL, $fdomain);

$fip = $_POST['ip'];
$fip = explode(PHP_EOL, $fip);

$array = [];

foreach ($fip as $key => $value) {
    $array [] = $fdomain[$key].' - '.$fip[$key];
}

print_r($array);
```